# Why are there only 6 <h> tags?

Tags: html

This has been boggling my mind for a while. While writing code, I noticed that there are only 6 `<h>` tags, which are:

- `<h1>`
- `<h2>`
- `<h3>`
- `<h4>`
- `<h5>`
- `<h6>`

I would really like to know why there are only 6, and not, well, an infinite number!

PS. I'm sorry if this is not the correct place to ask this question. If it isn't, please point out to me where I should instead ask this question.

Comment: They are just presets, you can define as many more size styles as you want in CSS.

Comment: Html is more like the structure of things while in css you can add more details to it.

Comment: @The Blue Dog Oh, but I don't! What exactly do you mean?

Comment: @TheBlueDog — Apparently not.

Comment: You can define as many as you want by creating new elements with JavaScript. Regardless, I suspect a large part of the reason there's not an _infinite_ number is because they get progressively smaller, and there's a lower limit to what size font people can read!

Comment: @TheBlueDog Actually you are wrong here

Comment: @Two-BitAlchemist thats too much of work, I would rather use a `div` with a class and target the element like `div.class_name h1 {size}` and so on

Comment: Altered comment slightly, happy now?

Comment: HTML didn't define any arbitrarily-nestable sectioning elements or a sectioning hierarchy prior to HTML5, so I suspect headings filled this role instead with their primitive numbering system, and they figured six levels of headings were enough for most documents. Of course, this is just conjecture on my part, hence not posting it as an answer.

Comment: @Mr.Alien: Cool, now I can get back to drinking my beer. ;)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

HTML was written as an SGML application. Each element type had to be defined explicitly (DTDs provide no way to define element types with wild cards), so an infinite number could not be defined.

6 was presumably chosen because it was assumed that nobody would need a sub-sub-sub-sub-sub-sub-heading. Very few documents come close to that level  of subdivision of sections.

The [sectioning rules](http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/multipage/sections.html#headings-and-sections) in HTML 5 effectively give an unlimited number of levels of headings, but tool support for the new sectioning algorithm is still weak.

Comment: @TobyvanKempen and btw don't get upset with the downvotes, it's just that the question was bit weird ;)

Comment: @Mr. Alien: It's not weird so much as the question is primarily based on conjecture, aka opinion.

Comment: @BoltClock Opinion may be a wrong word here, that's why I didn't voted to close as *Primarily Opinion Based* because this is related to standards, though it doesn't define that why only till h6.

Comment: Oh no, I'm not upset at the down votes! I actually knew I would get down-votes, because the question is, well, a tad "vague". This was a sacrifice I was willing to make for an answer that has been haunting me for a while.